# Add the same click listener to multiple element

Tags: jquery, click, listener, leaflet, cycle

i'm developing a web site using Javascript and jQuery for the first times. I created a map using Leaftlet library and Leaftlet clustering plugin. On that map i put about 300 markers that i get from a JSON file.
Then i bind a popup (info window) to every marker and then i add a click listener to the popup, so if an user click on it, a modal window is shown.

Here is my code:

```
function loadData(callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200")
      callback(xobj.responseText);
  }
  xobj.open("GET", "getData.php", true);
  xobj.send(null);
}

window.onload = function() {
  loadData(function(response) {
    var divClone = $("#userDetails").clone();
    users = JSON.parse(response);

    var map = L.map('map-canvas');

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover: true, maxClusterRadius: 64});
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      (function (cluster, user) {
    var marker = L.marker([users[i].lat, users[i].lon]);

    var myPopup = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoWindow');
    myPopup.innerHTML = "<div class='info'><p id='title'>" + users[i].name + "</p><p>" + users[i].city + "</p></div>";

    marker.bindPopup(myPopup);

    markers.addLayer(marker);

    // CLICK ON POPUP
    $(myPopup).on('click', function() {
      $("#userTitle").html(user.name).html();

      $("#userDesc").html(user.descr).html();

      $("#userAddr").html(user.city).html();

      $("#userEmail a").html(user.email).html();

      $("#userDetails").modal("show");
    });
      })(markers, users[i]); // function
    } // for cycle
    map.addLayer(markers);

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#userDetails").replaceWith(divClone.clone());
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see i add the same click listener to every marker. So the question is: it this the right way to reach my purpose? Do you know any better way to do it?
I would put the click event listener outside the for. How to do that?

Comment: What's wrong at it? My code works... i'm looking for a better way to get the same results. I would like to put the "click on popup" part outside the for cycle... so i can reuse it for other purposes. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do popup have unique class?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event only once using following:

```
// CLICK ON POPUP
$(document).on('click', '.popupClass', function() {
    $("#userTitle").html(user.name).html();

    $("#userDesc").html(user.descr).html();

    $("#userAddr").html(user.city).html();

    $("#userEmail a").html(user.email).html();

    $("#userDetails").modal("show");
});
```

Just update your `.popupClass` accordingly

Comment: Why the need to add one more class? Isn't the same to use just .info class?

Comment: @smartmouse Missed `,` Added!

Comment: I tried your code but it does not work. I discover that it doesn't trigger `.info`. I updated my question, please have a look: the click is triggered on `myPopup`, created before in the for cycle. So how to use it with your code since `myPopup` does not exist outside?

Comment: @smartmouse Add `popupClass` as shown in the code above

Comment: What is it related to? I do not have popupClass in my code. Where to add it?

Comment: @smartmouse If all popups have the same class, use it

Comment: I tried using .info instead of .popupClass but it doesn't trigger the modal